# How do I convert System::WideString to a char* and vice versa?

Tags: c++, char, c++builder, widestring

I have a situation where I need to compare a `char*` with a `WideString`.
How do I convert the WideString to a char* in C++?

Comment: Have you thought the other way around? (Converting the char* to a WideString)

Comment: Well both ways would be nice to know. However, I would prefer not to work with WideString.

Comment: Perhaps you could stretch the `char` type until it is wide enough? ;-)
Since the `char` type is smaller than the type used for a *WideString*, the better method is to convert the smaller to the larger then compare.

Comment: This is for C++ Builder, right? It would be a good idea to mention that in the question or at least in the tags.

Comment: Added tag to indicate Codegear 2009.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the wcstombs function.

[size_t wcstombs( char * mbstr, const wchar_t * wcstr, size_t max )](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs);

Comment: This got me over the finish line:
System::WideString wstr = "something";

char* buffer = new char[100];
wcstombs(buffer, wstr.data(), 100);

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See [WideCharToMultiByte()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(VS.85).aspx) and [MultiByteToWideChar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: This solution is Windows-Only though.

Comment: Yes, the C99 wcstombs()/mbstowcs() are covered in other answers.

Comment: Billy, so is the System::WideString type that's the topic of this question.

Answer (score 2):

To **compare** a [`System::WideString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.WideString) object with a `char*` (as the question *body* says you want to do), you can create a new `WideString` object from the pointer and then use ordinary `==` operator. The class has several constructors, including one for `const char*`.

```
char* foo = ...;
WideString bar = ...;
if (WideString(foo) == bar)
  std::cout << "They're equal!\n";
```

In fact, as long as the `WideString` object is on the left, you don't even need the constructor call because the pointer will be converted automatically.

```
if (bar == foo) { ... }
```

---

To **convert** a `WideString` to a `char*` (as the question *title* says you want to do), you might consider using the [`AnsiString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.AnsiStringT) type. They're convertible between each other. To get the ordinary pointer, call the [`c_str`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.AnsiStringT.c_str) method, just like you would with `std::string`.

```
WideString bar = ...;
AnsiString foo = bar;
std::cout << foo.c_str();
```

Comment: A *space*? That can't be right. A null character would cause truncation; if you have one that's not at the real end of the string, then use the two-argument version of the constructor so you can specify the real length. A space might cause truncation if you had something in a `std::istringstream` and you were reading a string from it with `stream >> stringvar`.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Actually, you mixed two different concepts:

- Widestring implies a buffer in UTF-16 encoding.
- char* may contain anything, from UTF-8 to ASCII-only text (in which case, this is convertable only if your widestring does not contain non-ASCII characters).

Please see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful about how to properly handle text.

Comment: wchar_t is defined to contain UTF-16 encoded data only on Windows.  It could be different for other OS's.  In general, it is locale dependent.

Comment: I have a thirdpartycomponent which provides a WideString. However, I need to compare that with a std::string so if it is not possible what options do I have?

Comment: Convert the other way around, then compare.